# What is the difference between following a post and bookmarking a question?

Tags: discussion, support, bookmarks, follow-post

I'm a bit confused about the difference of following a post/bookmarking a question: Aren't they of same use? More specifically, what's the advantage of following an answer compared to marking the whole post? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345783/546614) meta post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Zacky mentioned, there is a [proposed FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345783/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. That focuses on the facts; I wrote an answer to a [similar question on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15154/168837) about the advantages of both features:

> You should use the 'follow' feature when:
>
> - you want to receive inbox notifications
> - you want to keep the fact that you're following a post private
> - you want to keep a reference to an *answer*, not to a question
>
> You should use the 'bookmark' feature when
>
> - you don't want to receive inbox notifications (but just keep the question as a reference); multiple comments/edits can get annoying
> - you want an overview of all bookmarked question across the network in your network profile (the 'follow' feature only works on a per-site
>   base)
> - you want to help someone getting a [Favorite Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question)
>   badge

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. Since I will never remember which features attach to *follow* and which to *bookmark*, I have bookmarked the question and will follow the answer.